# Query with filters but only coping certain columns

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to take this formula `=QUERY('ABD1'!A1:Z,"Select * Where C = 'yes' and D = 'CAT'")` and have it only import columns A-F and M-S? And make the last entry, first.

Comment: It's not clear if "and make the last entry first" means that only the last entry should me moved or if you are looking to change the order of all results.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=QUERY('ABD1'!A:S,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S where C = 'yes' and D = 'CAT'")
```

If you want the first to be last you will have to specify what to order by.